# RaspberryPi can only send data to Arduino when using manual input

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I'm trying to send commands to an Arduino with a RaspberryPi using Python.

When I use `input()` to set the String it works completly fine and the command gets executet on the Arduino but when I use `sys.argv` or set the String in the code itself with `userInput = command` it doesn't.

When I set the String manually with `input()` and after that I overwrite it with `sys.argv` it works again.

Code on Arduino

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String data = Serial.readStringUntil(':');
    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.println(data);
    actionHandler(data);
  } 
}

void actionHandler(String data) {
   if(data == "command1")  {
      command1();
   } else {
    Serial.print("Wrong command! ");
    Serial.println(data);
   }
}

void command1() {
  print("Execute Command 1");
}
```

Code on RaspberryPi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import time
import sys

commands = ['command1',
'command2'
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    #userInput = input("Input command: ").lower()
    userInput = sys.argv[1].lower()

    if userInput in commands:
        payload = userInput + ":"
        ser.write(payload.encode('utf-8'))
        print(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip())
        print(ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip())
```

In this example the command won't be executed and the Arduino does not deliver any output. If I'd use the commented line to set the String it would work.

If I'd use both lines the argument would overwrite the manual input and it would work, too. The LED on the Arduino that indicates, that some data arrives blinks in any way.

I have no clue what's the problem here. Hope you can help me out. :)

Comment: why do you need to add ":"on the payload? have you tried without that. payload = userInput

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it needs to be converted to a byte array? I have had some similar issues and this usually fixed it. You could try to convert it.

```
ser.write(payload.encode())
```

Simply skipping utf-8
If that doesn't work, try this:

```
ser.write(bytes(payload))
```

Sorry if this didn't help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
I'll try it out in a few days. I temporarily fixed it by using Bash to send the data to the Arduino. That works relatively good.